# "Referenced workbook" popup message when opening Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hail, everybody!

**In short, my problem is, I wrote an Excel Addin which reference another Addin which, in turn, holds functions common to 4 addins/projects of mine. Each time I open Excel and it loads the addins (the 1 to 4 application installed Addins plus the referenced one holding the common functions), it gives the error message `This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed`. But none of my applications is trying to close the common one (neither on loading nor anywhere else in the code)!**

Describing in more detail.

I have four kinda-complex Excel applications I'd had developed for my job. Each one is a VBA project, distributed as Excel Addins (.xlam).

There are some functions common to all four projects (mostly data validation functions, GUI related functions, and external database query handling functions). Whenever I changed something in any of these functions, I had to re-write it in all four different applications and upload each one into Git.

Thus I got these common functions and put them aside in a fifth project, referenced the common project in the other ones (via Tools -> References). So now, all I have to do is to call them as any API outside referenced function (`commonProject.Function (arg1, arg2, arg3 etc)`).

So, the users will have the Addins for their applications (most use only one of the four) plus one "invisible" Addin holding the common functions.

The problem is, each time I open Excel and it loads the addins (the 1 to 4 application ones plus the referenced one holding the common functions), it gives the error message `This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed`.

**But none of my applications try to close the common one!**

I saw other posts about this popup, but they were about some referenced Addin actually being closed by another. I also saw this guy (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/this-workbook-is-currently-referenced-by-another/5c4fbf67-76f2-4870-a1da-9f9e4e72499d) with the same problem as me, but his conclusion was that it's not doable: he imported the common function module into the referer Addin.

Is this true? I can't have an Addin reference another without this annoying popup each time Excel loads? **Does anyone know another means to reference external functions which will not have this bumming collateral effect?**

Comment: Perhaps `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` can be inserted somewhere and then switched back to `True` after the loading.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. First, I'd used ```Debug.Print``` in the ```Open``` event of the different workbooks, and so learned in which order they load (it's in the same order the Addins had been installed). I thought the common functions addin would load first, but it hadn't. Then I set ```Application.DisplayAlerts``` to ```False``` in the ```Open``` events of each Addin, restarted Excel, but the popup appeared anyway. Reading the MSDN definition of ```Application.DisplayAlerts``, I learned it doesn't apply to every alert, but to most. It seems my unfortunate popup isn't handled by it...

Comment: Inspired by your idea, my next shot will be undoing the design time reference, creating the references in runtime, in the ```Open``` event of each project addin, and undoing them on ```Close```. But even if it work, I still have the feeling it's a lame workaround.

Comment: Seemingly lame workarounds are a fact of life in VBA programming, given how old the core technology is. The idea of creating references at runtime is clever. I hope it works.

Comment: ROTFL! I'll answer what happened.

Comment: When I try and create the reference at runtime, it returns an ```"Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"``` error. I'll open another question...

Comment: The other issue was solved. It worked! If you want to write the answer, fell at ease.

Comment: It is okay to answer your own question. It might help someone else.