# Name conflict error pops when creating reference at runtime, but not at design time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having this staggering problem in creating a reference at runtime.

**In short: I have an addin referenced in another addins, all created by myself and all working fine (except for some annoying popup which appears on loading Excel). As a workaround to this annoyance, I removed the existing reference to create it later, at runtime. But when I try creating the reference, it returns an `"Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"` error popup, and the reference is not created--which makes no sense, because if I create the reference at design time it works perfectly. There is no module or project with repeated name.**

Now explaining a little further.

I have four kinda-complex Excel applications I'd had developed for my job. Each one is a VBA project, distributed as Excel Addins (.xlam).

Additionally, I have a fifth project with functions common to the other four. This fifth project is referenced in the other ones (via Tools -> References). So now, all I have to do is to call them as any API outside referenced function (commonProject.Function (arg1, arg2, arg3 etc)).

Unfortunately, I had some problems with a popup message ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669589/referenced-workbook-popup-message-when-opening-excel)) and the workaround seems to be referencing the fifth project in the other ones at runtime.

In order to do this, I uninstalled three of the other four Addins, remaining only one, and used the following code in its `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strNamePath As String
    Dim bolAddinIsRefered as Boolean
    Dim oRef As Variant
    
    strNamePath = "c:\etc\etc\etc\Filename.xlam"
    
    For Each oRef In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
        If oRef.FullPath = strNamePath Then bolAddinIsRefered = True
    Next oRef
    
    If bolAddinIsRefered = False Then ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile strNamePath
    
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I used to create the reference at design time by hand, it worked mostly fine (except for the annoying popup I'm now trying to circumvent). But when I try creating the Reference at runtime, it returns an `"Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"` error popup, and the reference is not created.

I have verified the module and worksheet names and there is no duplicated one.

Does anyone have any idea how to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems after one and a half day struggling with a problem, when you ask the question on StackOverflow the solution just pops in your mind.

I'd already tried to change both projects names, even internal functions or subs resembling the same name. But I had not looked upon the FILE NAME!

As my solution is called Sisyphus, the filenames of all addins started with "Sisyphus"--"Sisyphus Common Functions.xlam", "Sisyphus DocMerge.xlam" etc.

**The problem was VBA was comparing the first word in filename.** I removed spaces and it worked well. Now my filenames are "SisyphusCommonFunctions.xlam", "SisyphusDocMerge.xlam" etc. and the referencing in runtime works all right.

Thank you for your time, I'll let this Question and Answer here, because it can be usefull to someone.